# Steam API all games

Tags: steam-web-api

I've been reading forums and trying Steam APIs, I'm searching for an API which provides all Steam Games.

I found the API providing all SteamApps, and the Steam Store API which provides information for Apps (I'm looking for the type: 'game'), but for this, I need to call the store API once for each SteamApp... And the Store API is limited to 200 calls every 5 minutes! Is it the only solution?

**EDIT:**

All Apps API : http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?key=STEAMKEY&format=json

App details API : [http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids={APP_ID}](http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=%7BAPP_ID%7D)

Answer (score 13):

There is no "Steam API all games and all their details in one go".

You use `GetAppList` to get all the steam apps. Then you have to query each app with `appdetails` which will take a long time.

- GetAppList : http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?format=json

```
{
  "applist": {
    "apps": [
      {"appid": 10, "name": "Counter-Strike"},
      {"appid": 20, "name": "Team Fortress Classic"},
      {"appid": 30, "name": "Day of Defeat"},
      {"appid": 40, "name": "Deathmatch Classic"}
    ]
  }
}
```

- appdetails : http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=10

```
{
  "10": {
    "success": true, 
    "data": {
      "type": "game",
      "name": "Counter-Strike",
      "steam_appid": 10,
      "required_age": 0,
      "is_free": false,
      "detailed_description": "...",
      "about_the_game": "...",
      "short_description": "...",
      "developers": ["Valve"],
      "publishers": ["Valve"],
      "EVEN_MORE_DATA": {}
    }
  }
}
```

There is a general API rate limit for each unique IP adress of 200 requests in five minutes which is one request every 1.5 seconds.

Another solution would be to use a third-party service such as [SteamApis](https://steamapis.com/) which offers more options but they are inevitably bound to what Steam offers in their API.

Comment: SteamApis third party is not providing data covering all games of Steam, but only the games that have a marketplace of items.
Also they don't provide all data you could get from official Steam API, like, as a example, tags.

Answer (score 6):

A common method here is to cache the results.

So for example, if your using something like PHP to query the results, you would do something like json_encode and json_decode with an array / object to hold the last results.

You can get fancy depending on what you want, but basically you'll need to cache and then perform an update of the oldest.

Comment: I actually did this recently to gather a collection of linux compatible games, Took around 4 days from memory. Tho i saved each initial ID into a SQL database ready for populate so i was able to use the update timestamps easily to determine the oldest.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small script that might be helpful. It allows you to get all the games you own, along with some sorting.

https://github.com/ghasani/steam_sorter/blob/main/steam_sorter.py

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

USER_API_KEY = 'INSERT STEAM API KEY'
USER_STEAM_ID = 'INSERT STEAM ID'

api = 'https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/'
res = requests.get(url=api)
dict = res.json()['applist']['apps']
data_clean = {}
for game in dict:
    data_clean[game['appid']] = game['name']

def get_name(id):
    return data_clean[id]

def get_score(id):
    data = requests.get(f'https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/{id}?json=1').json()['query_summary']
    score = data['total_positive']/data['total_reviews']
    return score

user_url = f'http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key={USER_API_KEY}&steamid={USER_STEAM_ID}&format=json'
user_game_data = requests.get(url=user_url).json()

games_owned_id = []
for result in user_game_data['response']['games']:
    games_owned_id.append(result['appid'])

my_games_and_user_scores = {}
for game_id in games_owned_id:
    try:
        my_games_and_user_scores[get_name(game_id)] = get_score(game_id)
    except:
        pass

df = pd.DataFrame(my_games_and_user_scores.items(), columns=('Game', 'User Score'))
df.sort_values(by=('User Score'), inplace=True, ascending=False, ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('~/Desktop/mygames.csv')
```