# Steam API - list all games based on TAG

Tags: steam-web-api

i've searched over google as well StackOverflow (found only this: [Steam API all games](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330864/steam-api-all-games))

What I'm trying to achieve is to list all games available in Steam store which will meet following criteria:
- include TAG: TPP
- will be a type: game (not a addon / soundtrack etc.)

How to proceed with that? I have no clue. Searched over github but there are only classes which are suppose to retrive specific user db.

current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?key=XXXXXX?tags=1697&os=win&category1=998%2C996&format=json'; // path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$characters = json_decode($data); // decode the JSON feed

echo $characters[0]->name;

var_dump($data);
var_dump($characters);

?>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($characters as $character) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $character->name; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `var_dump($data);` and `var_dump($characters);` for debugging purposes to see, what you get. When you open the API URL, you notice there is an `applist` entry in the JSON, which you don't read in your code.

Comment: Tested with the changes. And var_Dump shows nothing. Literally the page is blank. Being honest dont know how to address the issue with applist.

Comment: When you don't get any output at all (`var_dump()` produces always some output), you have to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death for error messages which are not seen.

Answer (score 1):

This API `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/` does not include steam tags.

You have to check every single app via the app detail call that is mentioned in the answer you linked. In this call you can also sort for app type. You are looking for app type 'game'.

As soon as you have a full database of all apps and their app details you can sort it the way you specified.

To my knowledge there are no other ways than those two calls or getting the tags directly from the steam store page.